# Word to express agnostic quality

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct form to express the agnostic quality of something.
The usual suffix **-ness** seems incorrect to me but I could not find a trustworthy reference to either confirm or deny this.

The only derived form I have encountered is the noun **agnosticism**

To describe my desired use case in an example:

> This system comprises a portal and a service
>   The portal needs to be fully agnostic of the service
>   The *agnosticness/agnosticity* of the portal is crucial

Edit: as @sojourner correctly deduced, I should have stated this more clearly, my example is indeed meant to be used in the field of computer science.

Comment: I see no reason why "agnosticness" wouldn't be a valid construction.

Comment: *skepticism, cynicism, doubtfulness, uncertainty, perplexity, indecisiveness, etc.* - You can use any of these, they all express a quality of unknowing.

Comment: The **lack of bias** of the portal is crucial, the **objectivity** of the portal is crucial.

Comment: The system COMPRISES a portal and a service.  Not "is comprised of".

Comment: The standard term for this, in this context, is ***neutrality***.

Comment: If anyone ever needed to express "the agnostic quality of something", the word is ***agnosticism***. I don't understand what else this question seeks, or why.

Comment: @FumbleFingers well as you can see from all the different comments and answers, there does not really seem to be consensus, so it does not seem like an unreasonable question, for a non native speaker, to me

Comment: @Pankrates: Sometimes it seems to me like half the answers to questions like this on ELU are from non-native speakers! Personally I think the whole concept of using ***agnostic*** in the technical context of a ***generic*** software interface is rather misguided, though I do recognise people do it more and more often these days.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that in computer science **agnosticy** (not agnosticness/agnosticity) is a proper word because [agnostic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agnostic) as a noun in (computing) means a software component (or other entity) `that is unaware or noncommittal regarding the specific nature of the components with which it interacts` (Wiktionary).Thus:

This system is comprised of a portal and a service.
The portal needs to be fully agnostic of the service.
The [agnosticy](https://bitbucket.org/keppla/homunculus/issue/19/database-agnosticy-for-setup) of the portal is crucial.

If however you want to use a close word, so to speak, the closest words I came across are: [independency](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/independency), autonomy and [noncommittance](http://www.smwcentral.net/?p=viewthread&t=56602).

Comment: I use the term "agnostic" when describing the "chuck" attached to many bicycle tire pumps.  Such a chuck can automatically adapt between Schrader and Presta valves, without user intervention.

Comment: ([link](https://bitbucket.org/keppla/homunculus/issue/19/database-agnosticy-for-setup) to example usage is dead)

Answer (score -1):

Agnosticism seems to be a valid word.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosticism ;This link has many references to back it up as well, one being: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4076;jsessionid=BC40E32960B872A2DEB9F581A837801A?redirectedFrom=agnosticism#eid

Comment: We already knew that.